# Maximum frequency that can be converted with Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, sampling, adc

Arduino Uno Board use successive approach ADC of 12 bits and 16 MHz frequency clock. What is the maximum voice frequency can be converted using arduino uno board? 
I want the step by step solution with calculations.